# Olympus air a01

Tags: olympus-camerakit, olympus-air

Is it possible to control camera through cable?

Cannot find that in documentation

Looking for small factor camera that could have great quality, but at the same time works well for development.

Answer (score 0):

No.

AIR A01 supports USB mass storage class only. So, AIR A01 cannot capture image with using USB connection.